# Searching a Spring MVC with Hibernate project for understanding

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, sample

I am working currently on Spring and Hibernate together. As this is just the start of project, I would like to integrate MVC components into it. I have tried to make some of my own, but unfortunately I am faced with problems. If there is any sample project which uses Hibernate for persistence and Spring MVC dispatcher, kindly let me know. A few of them on the internet don't seem to be up to date and are more problematic then useful. Kindly let me know. Thank you for your time. :-)

Comment: Please google it, you will find many examples. Once you try those, and face issue, please post you code here :)

Comment: Already tried 2 projects, all of them fail even after updating code and all. Working on a 3rd one now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the foolowing archetype [Spring MVC quickstart archetype](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) to generate a simple project can use maven like build tool, spring like application container and Hibernate or Jpa like persistence framework

Comment: Thank you, this seems promising. :-)